# Oraclize callback is not called with more data in it

Tags: solidity, oracles

I have very strange experience with Oracle. When I try to add functionality inside of callback, callback is not called, but when I delete functionality callback works without problem.

I tried to increase gas amount using oraclize_setCustomGasPrice, use mapping, arrays and anything I know in functionality, nothing works.

Here are example of callback which is never called:

```
function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
  if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) revert();
  emit LogPriceUpdated(result);
 for (uint i=0; i < betId + 1; i++) {
    if (compareStrings("up", result)) {
        gameInfo[currentPrizePeriodTime][i].choice = result;
  }
 }
}
```

And here is example of code which is called all the time:

```
function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
  if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) revert();
    emit LogPriceUpdated(result);
  }
}
```

Does any of you why this happens, is it solvable or I should look for workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Oraclize* employee here, and looking at your code with a `__callback` I'm pretty sure the Oracle you are referring to is indeed *Oraclize*, so hopefully I can help! :p

Without seeing the rest of your smart-contract I can't diagnose for sure what is stopping your `__callback` from running, though I can certainly make some educated guesses. It is almost certainly failing due to out-of-gas errors since you're using both `strings` & a loop inside it. *Any* string manipulation is very expensive in solidity in terms of gas, and looping *over* some form of string manipulation is will *multiply* that cost for each time the loop turns.

When you call an Oraclize query you have the option of supplying an *amount* of gas to the query, which amount is taken from your contract at the time you make the call. (This is different to the `setCustomGasPrice` that you've mentioned) Oraclize will then supply this amount to power the transaction that runs your `__callback`. If you don't supply this parameter, it defaults to 200,000. That's *plenty* to run your `__callback` with most of the logic removed, but unlikely to be enough depending on how long your string result is & how many times you iterate over it with in the loop.

To supply more gas to the Oraclize query, add the number as a param thusly:

```
     oraclize_query("URL", queryString, gasAmount);
```

where `gasAmount` is a uint of how much gas you wish to supply & the `queryString` is whatever you're currently using to make your queries. This way you can add more gas to the transaction and get the `__callback` to go through when it includes your logic.

However, the bigger issue is that you're trying to do a *lot* of expensive stuff in your `__callback`, and the name of the game in Solidity is tying to make *everything* as efficient as possible since it all costs money to run. It's probably worth you having a look at your current architecture & see where you can make gas-cost savings in what you do with the results of your Oraclize query.

Comment: Also for new developers using Oraclize like me, firstly make sure you really do not have nulls in your callback, like I did ^^

Comment: @TomasMaksimavicius yes! :P It's often a good idea to "mock" the callback by pulling it out into it's own function and using say the Truffle testing framework to call your mock with the result you expect to receive from Oraclize. Decoupling it this way lets you test that the logic is working correctly separate to the Oraclize query itself.

Comment: Have the same issue... Will it make any difference to put all the logic in an internal function and call it from the __callback()?

Comment: @Ruham - it makes no difference whatsoever. So long as the logic inside the internal function has no errors, and you provide necessary gas price to the Oraclize call to power that callback, you can arrange your logic the way you describe with no problems.